# Documentation - Can't edit many sections of draft

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-editor, documentation-drafts

Issue with documentation editor for **drafts**.

When I click on "pencil" icon near the Introduction section (or Introduction in draft's summary panel), it doesn't seem to work. The same thing is happening to other sections (Syntax, Parameters) when I keep them occasionally empty. There are no errors in the console.

The Examples section is all fine.

I have no blocking extensions enabled. No connection problems.

The Remarks section is non-editable too since it is outlined.

### 12/17/16 update

It became more buggy on first draft editing, but after page refresh all problems solve themselves. The thing is that on draft creation you type something in the Introduciton section, save it, then try to edit, and get unnecessary wrappers, so you are not able to edit before you refresh the page. I have latest version of Chrome and nothing is printed into console. But when I click on "edit" button, it just adds wrapper container inside of other container in section. It reminds me a recursion effect.

[image: Buggy behaviour of first edit draft page]

*Note.* Text in the box is just contents of the Remarks section.

Comment: Yes I am experiencing the same thing. I can edit answers and questions but when I click edit in the documentation section and move the mouse cursor above the edit the cursor changes into a no-edit-cursor.

Answer (score 1):

We had an issue where the editor placement code wasn't being triggered correctly.

A fix is out now. Please let me know if you're still running into problems with edit links. Thanks!

Comment: It became more buggy after update.

Comment: But now I can edit draft normally after first creation! Thanks.

Comment: Other bug appeared, see in post.

Comment: @VINTproYKT Hmm. I can't reproduce that one. I'll try again on Monday. In the meantime, can you do me a favor and post the new issue as a separate bug report so that it's easier for us to keep track of it? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear I can't edit either. See my comment to the question above.